# Whether to preemptively answer a question I know is coming or wait for it to be asked

Tags: communication, management

I will send a department-wide email announcing, and explaining, changes to an existing process.  After this email we will be having a town hall-style meeting to explain and answer questions about the process. I want to determine whether to preemptively answer a few of the questions I anticipate others will ask in the initial email, or wait to let them be asked during the town hall.

Is it more empowering to constituents to ask questions themselves (and, conversely, disrespecting to preempt them from doing so) or is it as/more appropriate to empathetically communicate "I assume you have questions about why this decision was made" and then present those questions/answers in a one-way format (email) first, with the assumption that a dialogue will follow?

### Background

Constituents are aware that we have been working on revamping the process in question and I don't expect resistance to the fact that the process will be changing. But some will have concerns about why certain specific changes were selected instead of other specific changes.

I know there will be some questions I do not anticipate, and I don't want the kick-off communique to be a 15-minute read. The process will evolve as we collectively agree on what is working and what is not so I want to encourage conversation and engagement, but I also am mostly firm on the way we'll be doing things initially because we had to choose one or the other.

Think of the process change decisions in question as A/B testing that we cannot do simultaneously so we have to start with either choice A or choice B. Like a cafeteria line that moves from right to left or left to right and we can only have one line at any given time. (Please humor me by refraining from responding with actual cafeteria line efficiency studies -- this is just an example.)

My motivations for allowing questions to be asked in person are

- it respectfully does not presume to speak for my colleagues
- it engages the group in discussion
- I find that being allowed to speak my thoughts is cathartic and assume the same applies to some number of my colleagues

Comment: This is very difficult to answer with only the information provided.   How large is your company?   Are you in a leadership role - do people know who you are and will they be predisposed to listen to you?   How is information normally distributed?   etc.

Comment: If you are firm in the way things are done initially then just put that in the process.  If decisions were already made then why not just explain them.  To wait for questions to me is manipulative.

Comment: @Roger I've updated the question (and description) to clarify. I'm interested less in process change-related advice and more on thoughts around  preemption. The group I'm communicating with is about 30 in count and predisposed to listen to me. Significant changes are often announced in an email and followed up with a town hall-style meeting. Usually (and true in this case) constituents are aware that a change in process, etc. has been under consideration.

Answer (score 3):

> When introducing a new process, should I address questions sent via
>   email or wait for the roll out meeting and address them to everyone?

When introducing a new process, there is no way you will anticipate all the potential questions your folks will have.  Some questions may bring things to light you may not even have considered.  (and may require a bit of diligence on your part)

I would provide a preemptive rough draft of the process first for the appropriate people to digest.  Then, take all the questions and items and include them in your presentation and then hold your roll-out meeting.

At the roll-out presentation, I would then answer all questions received if you can.  If not, its okay to say "*Hey, I had not considered that, let me get back to you*".  The reason for this approach is simple:  Most likely other people will have the same questions, and you will be more efficient answering them once than in multiple emails.

Consistency and transparency are key in getting the right people to buy into the new process.

Comment: Sometimes even if you have considered it... go consider it some more. People will appreciate the fact that you took their question back to consider it. Even if your answer doesn't change, it shows you take their feedback seriously!

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't have to be mutually exclusive.  I'd suggest answering the person who asked the question by email to ensure that you are actively addressing concerns but not take that response company wide until the town hall meetings.  In the town hall meeting begin the question period with "questions asked in the last few days".  This approach helps in that (shockingly) not everyone reads emails but some people do.  Presenting info to the crowd that some of the group has already heard from you really risks losing the attention of the room.  The other benefit is that you are priming the pump for the question period.  If people hear that their colleague wanted clarification on some point they are more likely to express their own clarification requests.

I have additional advice in this regard.  The way that process changes most often fail in my experience is lack of clarity in parameters.  Often people end up unclear on exactly who they apply to and when they take effect.  In the first few lines of the company wide email indicate who this impacts and when it takes effect.